# Can anyone explain the following Javascript code behaviour?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var subRow = [];
var rowarr = [];
subRow.push({ v: "Jay" });
subRow.push({ v: "Ram" });
rowarr.push({ c: subRow });
subRow.length = 0;
subRow.push({ v: "Jay1" });
subRow.push({ v: "Ram1" });
rowarr.push({ c: subRow });
console.log(JSON.stringify(rowarr));
```

The output is:

```
    [{
    "c": [{
        "v": "Jay1"
    }, {
        "v": "Ram1"
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "Jay1"
    }, {
        "v": "Ram1"
    }]
}]
```

The expected output is:

```
    [{
    "c": [{
        "v": "Jay"
    }, {
        "v": "Ram"
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "Jay1"
    }, {
        "v": "Ram1"
    }]
}]
```

Can anyone explain why it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are handled by reference.

`subRow.length = 0;` erases the contents of the array.

`rowarr` then contains two pointers to the same array (which only has the content in it that you put there after emptying it)

Change `subRow.length = 0;` to `subRow = []` to work on a new array instead of modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

`subRow` points to an object. When you `push` it onto `rowArr` you create a reference to that object. You push it twice, that's two references to one object. When you edit `subRow` both references to the object see the changes, so you've trampled all over the old contents of the object - they are not stored anywhere else, so they are completely lost. You need to create a brand new object instead of editing the old object.